# Get data from one page to another in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image]

I want to know how to add inputted data from one page to another page like in the picture above with angular.

I have a home page where I have an input field and a button that leads to a second page. On the home page I want to add a name in the input field and on the second page I want that inputted name to appear. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options:

- Make the first page input field a form, and submit to your controller. Store the data, and return it when someone goes to the next page (wouldn't suggest this one)
- Take the first page field input and make it a route parameter for the second page
- Store the data temporarily in [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)